# How to gracefully close aioredis pool in aiohttp server?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp, aioredis

I create redis pool the following way:

```py
async def create_redis_connection_pool(app) -> aioredis.Redis:
    redis = aioredis.from_url(
        "redis://localhost", encoding="utf-8", decode_responses=True, max_connections=10,
    )
    app["redis"] = redis
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        await loop.create_task(app["redis"].close())
```

Then I use the function when I create the Aiohttp app:

```py
def init() -> web.Application:
    app = web.Application()

    ...
    app.cleanup_ctx.append(create_redis_connection_pool)
    ...
    return app
```

When I start server, do at least one request which use redis pool and then do `Cnrl+C` I get the following warning message:

```
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Connection.disconnect' was never awaited
```

How to solve the issue and gracefully close Redis connection pool? I do tests in Mac OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `redis==4.2.0` (`from redis import asyncio as aioredis`) or later,
pass `close_connection_pool=True` when you call `.close()`:

```py
await app["redis"].close(close_connection_pool=True)
```

Otherwise, for `aioredis==2.0.1` (latest version as of this answer) or earlier,
call `.connection_pool.disconnect()` after `.close()`:

```py
await app["redis"].close()
await app["redis"].connection_pool.disconnect()
```

Reference: https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis-py/pull/1256

Comment: Thank you very much! I use `aioredis==2.0.1`, your code snipped solved the problem.